# How to remove updown arrows in numeric textbox in windows forms application

Tags: windows, forms, visual-studio-2010, textbox, numeric

I am trying to create a windows  form application and I need to add a numeric textbox in it. Is there any way to not to have the up and down arrows in this textbox.

I am a newbie plese help.

Regards
Manish Kathuria

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0; 
}
```